# Dialog not closing react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-popup-dialog

I am using the [React native popup dialog](https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-popup-dialog) package. I'm trying to close the dialog `onPress` and then navigate away from the screen. The navigation is happening, but the dialog remains open. And a warning `Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component` is shown.

```
    <Dialog
    dialogStyle = {{textAlign:'center'}}
    visible={this.state.dialogVisible}
    height = {150}
    dialogAnimation={new SlideAnimation({
    slideFrom: 'bottom',
    })}
    >
      <DialogTitle
      title = {"Information"}
      textStyle = {{textAlign:'center',fontFamily:'raleway-regular',color:'#4abce3'}}
      />
      <DialogContent style = {{justifyContent:'center',alignContent:'center'}}>
        <Text>{this.state.requestResult}</Text>
        <Button
          title = "Okay!"
          onPress = {()=>{ this.navigate() }}
          type = "outline"
          buttonStyle = {styles.dialogButton}
          titleStyle = {styles.choiceButtonTitle}
        />
      </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
```

The `navigate()`function

```
    navigate = () => {
      const { navigation } = this.props;
      this.setState({dialogVisible:false})
      navigation.navigate('Home'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is `async`, which does not block the execution. When `setState` gets called next line executes (`setState` is yet to complete) and you got navigated to `Home`.

You can you callback in `setState` for navigation.

```
navigate = () => {
      const { navigation } = this.props;
      this.setState({dialogVisible:false}, () => navigation.navigate('Home')) 
}
```

Comment: Hey Ravi, the behavior is still the same. Navigation happens, but dialog remains open.

Comment: Post your Wrapper `Dialog` where you have used `this.state.dialogVisible`.